# How to enforce that all variants of an enum can be returned from a function

Tags: rust, enums

I'm implementing the trait `FromStr` for an enum, and I want to make sure that I'm covering all variants of the enum. Is there a way to tell Rust to throw a compile-time error if some enum variants are not returned by the function?
For example, I don't want the code below to compile since the variants `E::b` and `E::c` are not returned by any path.

```rust
fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
    match s {
        "a" => Ok(E::a),
        _ => Err("no"),
    }
}
enum E {
    a,
    b,
    c,
}
```

I'm looking for a more general solution than just for implementing the `FromStr` trait since I plan to use a similar pattern for other functions as well.

Comment: dead code warnings will tell you when a given enum variant is never constructed. Besides that, no.

Comment: I'd recommend a crate: [strum_macros](https://docs.rs/strum_macros/0.24.3/strum_macros/index.html) - Then it does it for you, and you don't need to worry about missing one either.

Comment: I remember there was an https://internals.rust-lang.org thread about introducing a warning for things like that, but I can't find it now.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to make the Rust compiler enforce that (apart from what PitaJ suggested in a comment - a dead code warning for variants that have never been constructed, but it's clear that "trick" wouldn't work in most real-world cases).

However, there are multiple crates that can do that string-to-variant conversion for you. One such crate is [`strum_macros`](https://crates.io/crates/strum_macros). It provides the [`EnumString`](https://docs.rs/strum_macros/0.24.3/strum_macros/derive.EnumString.html) macro, which seems exactly like what you want.

Not only will such a macro guarantee you haven't forgotten a variant, but you will also avoid the need to write quite a bit of boilerplate code.

Comment: I'm actually looking for a more general solution than just for `from_str` and with different strings instead of the same as the enum variants name, since I plan to use a similar pattern for a few other things too. Thanks for your answer, though, I will check the `strum_macros` crate this evening and see if it satisfies my requirement.

Comment: @MaheshBansod many of those crates allow you to specify alternative strings and matching rules. So that _may_ be an option. But I understand even that could be insufficient.